# How do I get Yocto git fetcher to pull specfic file with subpath parameter?

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto

I am trying to fetch the linux COPYING file automatically for a kernel driver I am developing with the Yocto git fetcher from:

```
https://github.com/torvalds/linux
```

When I try this:

```
git://github.com/torvalds/linux.git;protocol=https;branch=master;subpath=COPYING
```

in my `SRC_URI` recipe parameter it obviously fails as COPYING is not a folder. Where it in a subfolder of the repository it would have worked.

So my question is: How do I get it to use the COPYING file without having to pull the whole linux filesystem.

Note: I know that I can just copy the file locally and I have managed to get it working by referencing the https:// link to the specific file, but this copies the whole HTML that contains COPYING which is definitely not what I want. I was just wondering whether it is possible to fetch a single file as explained above.

Comment: Use the link to the raw file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torvalds/linux/master/COPYING

Comment: Great, that works, thank you very much! A note for people that have this problem in the future is to delete the license file (e.g. COPYING) and the license-destdir in your build directory as well, as bitbaking the updated recipe  won't overwrite them.